# Datepicker: cut off on small displays

Tags: angular, scroll, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to show the complete datepicker calendar in a small screen, but it is not possible to access to the whole calendar.

There is no scroll, and no possibilities to reach all the content of the datepicker when the display is smaller than the datepicker.

It happens with any datepicker, for example that from the official page:

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Steps to reproduce:

1. Reduce the navigator window, to a heigh of no more than 300px
2. Open the datepicker
3. Try to access the hole days (It isn't possible)

Environment
Angular: 9.0.2

CDK/Material: 9.0.1

Browser(s): Chrome & Firefox (Last versions)

Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

just in your styles.css (or styles.scss)

```
.mat-calendar {
    width: 200px!important;
    height: 260px!important;
    font-size:.9em
}
@media(min-width:257px)
{
  .mat-calendar {
    font-size:1em;
    width: 250px!important;
    height: 324px!important;
  }
}
@media(min-width:300px)
{
  .mat-calendar {
    width: 296px!important;
    height: 354px!important;
  }
}
```

NOTE: You can change the mediaquery size at your requeriments